# Syntax highlighting of math in markdown file

Tags: syntax, markdown, syntax-highlighting, mathjax, inline-code

So far I only found editors (some more and some less lightweight) for syntax highlighting of `Markdown`. However, I often use `math` inside my markdown files and then render it all using a template and pandoc. So I'm searching for an editor, which is intelligent enough to syntax highlight math within a markdown file, while also highlighting the markdown syntax. Afaik this usage of math is increasing. Just look at pandoc and Jupyter for example.

Is there an editor, which can do that or do you know about any geany, sublime text or atom plugins for that?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an editor, which can do that or do you know about any geany, sublime text or atom plugins for that?

The problem is that Markdown doesn't has native math support so the syntax highlight will not be 100% accurate except that you match the plugin with the Markdown to HTML conversion program. For example, Pandoc has some "complicate" rules for when `$` will start or not the math mode and some conversion program only accept `$$`.